# Does Srimad Bhagawatam make use of Alwar poetry?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, alwar

I remember reading that somewhere and it makes sense since Bhagavatam has a distinct South Indian feel to it.  This also has implications for its date.

Comment: No, Bhagavatam doesn't use Alwar poetry.

Comment: All the puranas make mention of religious philosophies dated before 1 ad like shiva purana mentioning the pashuapata system, the devi purana mentioning Tantra, the vaishnava purana mentioning bhagvata and panchratra movements, the westerners give date around 1 ad but these philosophies were around from dwapara to 500bc-700ad until coming of shankara, the alwars are also dated to 1bc but that's not the date believed by traditionalists.

Comment: My eyes glaze over when I see words like "dwapara"

Comment: @SK but that's what the scriptures say the avatars of Lord shiva and Lord Vishnu, sage narayana and sage lakulisa were avatars in starting of dwapara yugas.

Comment: Hinduism has no real notion of time.